# Discord.py - How can I make cogs per-server

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have a public bot that has cogs, but I just tested that if I load/unload a cog then it'll load/unload that cog across every server it's in, this of course is something that's horrible for a public bot

I'll show my load & unload command:

````py
@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
 client.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")

 await ctx.send(f"Successfully loaded the {extension} module :thumbsup: ")

@load.error
async def load_error(ctx, error):
 await ctx.send(f"The following error occured:```\n{error}\n```")
````

is the load command, and:

````py
@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
 client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")

 await ctx.send(f"Successfully unloaded the {extension} module :thumbsup: ")

@unload.error
async def unload_error(ctx, error):
 await ctx.send(f"The following error occured:```\n{error}\n```")
````

is the unload command

Edit: I wouldn't mind trying something other than what I'm attempting

Comment: You'll have to program your cogs such that they're aware of where the commands are invoked from and ignore them on certain guilds.

Comment: I probably wouldn't know how to do that, and I wouldn't be able to set it per server it joins since anyone can invite the bot

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [cog_check](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Cog.cog_check) to check each command in a cog: eg

```py
class MyCog(commands.Cog):
   def cog_check(self, ctx):
      return ctx.guild.id == 123
```

Since cogs are bound to the bot, loading and unloading them will effect the bot everywhere, there is no better way to make guild only cogs than using this.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this would be adding a simple check to each command in the cogs you don't want public

```
#add a check to the top of the cog
def isPrivateCommand():
    async def predicate(ctx):
        return ctx.guild.id == YOURGUILDIDHERE
    return commands.check(predicate)

.
.
.

@commands.command
@isPrivateCommand()
async def ...
```

This check should make sure that the command will only be executed in your guild (the guild ID you put in the check).

Documentation on checks can be found [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#checks) for discord.py rewrite

Happy coding!

Comment: That's not what I'm aiming to do.. I'm not sure how I can explain it, I simply just want the cogs per server, meaning someone can load it in one server and it won't effect other servers. eg, someone uses ".load chat" (loads the chat cog) then someone does ".unload chat" (unloads the chat cog) it'll keep the cog loaded in the server where they loaded it, and keep it unloaded in the server they unloaded it in

Comment: Ah okay I see - in that case what you could do is save info on which server has loaded which cog in a database, and then add a custom check to each command to check if that server has the cog for that command loaded or not. Apart from that, there's no real way to load/unload cogs server specific as the loading happens for the entire bot application itself. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

cogs belong to the bot, not to a server. So what you try to do is not possible.
But (i guess you want to do something like dyno has to activate commands in a guild)

you can save all guilds that "loaded" a command in a database and then add a check to all commands if they are loaded

```py
example_data = {
    "command_name": "example",
    "loaded_guilds": []
}


def isCommandLoaded():
    async def predicate(ctx):
        return ctx.guild.id in example_data["loaded_guilds"]:
    return commands.check(predicate)



@commands.command()
@isCommandLoaded()
async def example(self, ctx):
    """Example ..."""
```

than just build a load/unload command and save it to the db

Answer (score 0):

in a settings.py

```
def GuildsAktive() -> (int, ...):
    GUILDXYZ = 12312213121213121312      # NOQA
    return [GUILDXYZ]
```

in your bot file

```
    async def test_sync_tree(self):
        guilds = []
        for gid in settings.GuildsAktive():
            x = await self.fetch_guild(gid)
            guilds.append(x)
        return guilds
```

in your COG

```
async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(YOURCOG(bot), guilds=await bot.test_sync_tree())
```

Answer (score -1):

at the setup from cog you could define an Guild array were to sync the tree

```
async def setup(bot):
     await bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot), guilds=[discord.Object(id=...)])
```

now u only need a function that returns all gildsid/where_cogs_synced
and u will solve your problem...